# Compiling a maven project with class from external jar file (that is not in a maven artifact)

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm somewhat new to java, and very new to maven.  I might use some terminology imperfectly.

As I develop my project that I'm using use maven to build, as I've needed classes that aren't part of the core java language I've added an appropriate `<dependency>` section to my `pom.xml` (usually copied from mvnbrowser.com without my really understanding it very well), and I've been able to use the classes I want.  Works great.

Now I've encountered a java class that I want to use that is apparently not available in a maven artifact.  It's `com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder` which is distributed with the android SDK.  I wrote a standalone java program to get my code working; I compile it with `javac` and not with maven, and that works fine.  For that, I put the jar file that contains the class I want, `sdklib.jar`, into my `jre/lib/ext` directory (`/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/jre/lib/ext` on a FreeBSD machine), and my `import com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder` line compiles fine and I can refer to `ApkBuilder` and use it with no problems.

Now, when I copied my working code into my maven project, and tried to build with `mvn project`, I get `package com.android.sdklib.build does not exist` errors on the import line, and `cannot find symbol: class ApkBuilder` errors where I refer to `ApkBuilder`.

Looking around the net, I found `android-maven-plugin` here: http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/.  It referred me to `maven-android-sdk-deployer` here: https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer.  These leads sounded promising at first, but as far as I can tell, their purpose is for developing android applications using maven, which is not what I'm trying to do.  I just want my java program to manipulate android `apk` files, but my java program itself is not to be run on an android device.  Also, the android SDK is made to work with linux, not FreeBSD which I'm using, so I cannot follow the installation instructions for `maven-android-sdk-deployer`.  I also found an artifact called `maven-apkbuilder-plugin` but that also seems to be for the purpose of creating android applications and I didn't see documentation for it.  So I haven't pursued these leads.

It seems the easiest thing would be just to get the compiler to look in my `jre/lib/ext` folder for the `sdklib.jar` file when running `mvn package`.  But maybe that's not the way to go.  Or maybe there's a simple change I can make to my `pom.xml` that will cause the compiler to find `sdklib.jar`.  I looked at the pom documentation at http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Settings, but didn't see a way to do that.  Anyway, I'm sure there's at least one solution; I just don't know it (yet).

What are my options?  What's the best way to use the `ApkBuilder` class in my maven-built project?  What should I have read that would have enabled me to answer this question myself?  Thanks!!

Comment: You have correctly identified the source of the problem -- the JAR missing from the classpath.  Force-feeding the `jre/lib/ext` is not ideal.  Try researching some Maven+Android development tools (I don't know anything about Android dev).  M2e-Android (http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) seems intriguing.  It claims that "It brings the power of Maven dependency management into the ADT"

Answer (score 8):

If you're just trying to reference the jar, the simplest solution might be to add the jar to your local repository manually. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for details.

Nutshell:

```
mvn install:install-file       \
    -Dfile=<path-to-file>      \
    -DgroupId=<group-id>       \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
    -Dversion=<version>        \
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

You *may* use whatever you want for the `group-id`, `artifact-id`, and `version`, but they should be something resembling what you'd expect if it was available in the repo.

Since you're not actually creating an Android project, this may be sufficient.

---

*Here's how I would have asked the question.*

How can I use a library not available from a Maven repository in my Maven build?

(Coincidentally, that, and shorter variations of that, should bring up the links you "should" have read, to answer your last question :)