# How to use an RPM dependency in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, struts, redhat, rpm

All versions of struts1 have multiple vulnerabilities

CVE-2016-1182
CVE-2015-0899
CVE-2016-1181
CVE-2014-0114
CVE-2012-1007

I need to use a patched version but apache did not release patches for struts1 since it's well beyond its EOL, and as far as I know, only Redhat provided fixes for these vulnerabilities.

I need to use this version in my Maven project but I am not sure how to include an RPM dependency in the project? and how to even test it since I am using windows?

I looked at RPM maven plugin but all the usage scenarios on the official website seem to be centered around using it to produce an RPM from a Maven project, not the other way around, using an RPM in a Maven project.

Edit:
I also considered installing the package using yum and then use system scope and specify the location using systemPath but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: You can always add dependencies manually as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/8275260/438992. I don't know about using a non-Maven-repo artifact directly.

Comment: That would be my final resort but I wanted to check if there is a better solution because I don't want to have to ship the jars with the code.

Comment: You don't, you'd ship a script that would grab the dependencies and install them locally, or you'd use Maven to shade them and include them in your own artifact, or create an über-jar.